# Ошибка при выполнении Run - Run, IntelliJ IDEA 2017.3.1 + Tomcat 7.0.82

Tags: java, linux, intellij-idea, tomcat

Всем привет!

Пытаюсь создать веб-приложение, опираясь на материал статьи https://habrahabr.ru/post/240033/ 
в IDEA сервер добавил корректно, но при выполнении Run - Run:

```
10:32   All files are up-to-date
10:32   All files are up-to-date
10:32   Error running 'Unnamed': Error copying configuration files from /opt/tomcat/conf to /home/username/.IntelliJIdea2017.3/system/tomcat/Unnamed_ToDoList/conf: /opt/tomcat/conf/web.xml (Отказано в доступе)
```

Не совсем понимаю, почему возникает ошибка, какие права нужно настроить и под каким пользователем. Буду очень благодарен за помощь. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Tomcat настраивал по гайду https://www.8host.com/blog/ustanovka-apache-tomcat-8-v-ubuntu-16-04/ 
пользователя tomcat (его создавали в статье) сейчас удалил, ошибка осталась

Comment: Выполни команду `ls -la /opt/tomcat/conf/web.xml`. Вероятно у твоего пользователя (username) нет прав для чтения указанного файла

Comment: Спасибо большое за помощь, проблема была в правах.